# PDFsharp DrawRoundedRectangle parameters

Tags: c#, drawing, pdfsharp, ellipse, drawellipse

I would like to use the PDFsharp method

```
DrawRoundedRectangle(
    XPen pen,
    double x,
    double y,
    double width,
    double height,
    double ellipseWidth,
    double ellipseHeight
)
```

for the definition of a clipping path.
It works - but I don't get what the last two parameters define exactly. Therefore I am not able to sepcify correctly how my rounded corners are constructed.

So - What exactly is the method doing with the ellipse (which seems to be defined by width and heigth properties only)?

Answer (score 1):

The straight lines of the rectangle are connected by a quarter of an ellipse in every corner. And you specify the size of the ellipse, thus limiting the lengths of the straight lines.

Of course, you will get quarters of a circle in the corners if both values for the ellipse are the same.